# LaTeX story/myth: Package with line made out of superimposed letters of author’s name?

Tags: packages, line, fun

I’m trying to track down and verify an amusing LaTeX anecdote that I read or heard a while back:  There was some graphics/diagrams package, and some commonly-used command from it, where what looked like a line in the output was not really implemented as a line, but as many superimposed tiny copies of the letters of the package author’s name (or perhaps the package name), so that every document using the package would contain a hidden “signature” from it.

My original vague memory was that this was [Paul Taylor’s `diagrams` package](http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/), which does have some features reminiscent of this — it contains a time-bomb (it throws a error if the version you’re using is more than a few years old) and gives an attribution requirement as a condition of use.  But searching around, I can’t find a source for this specific story, either for `diagrams` or for any other package.  Can anyone else place this story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent version of `diagrams.sty`, released December 2019, is no longer obfuscated. It still contains the time bomb, though.

Reading the code, we see (lines 4045-4099) a macro `\the@signature` which builds a horizontal rule from segments corresponding to the Morse code for “PAUL” (plus additional code for “TAYLOR”, commented out).

```
%=======================================================================%
%                                                                       %
%       (8A) SIGNATURE                                                 %
%                                                                       %
%=======================================================================%
%
% Now test whether we have enough space to put our Morse Code signature on the
% stretching horizontal. Only do it in diagrams, where both fillers are "-",
% there is no middle, there is enough space and the rule breadth is positive.
% Do it on the 10th and then every 20th subsequent such occasion.
%
\def\test@signature{%
\ifincommdiag
   \ifx\@filla\@fillh
      \ifx\@fillb\@fillh
         \ifdim\dimen3>\z@\else
            \ifdim\dimen2>93\pixel@size % corrected 24.6.94 for P
            \ifdim\dimen2>18\p@ % added 24.6.94 for high resolution
               \ifdim\intended@breadth>\z@
                  \count@\signature@countdown
                  \advance\count@\m@ne
                  \ifnum\count@<\z@
                     \count@ 20%
                     \let\@signature\the@signature
                  \fi
                  \xdef\signature@countdown{\the\count@}%
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
%\showthe\skip2 %\expandafter\message{\signature@countdown}%
}%
% Dots, dashes and spaces are 2, 6 and 2 pixels wide, 1 pixel high.
% However at over 596 dpi resolution this unit is increased:
% \dimen2= 3pixels=0.17pt at 1270dpi, and 6pixels=.17pt at 2540dpi
\def\@morse#1{\vrule\horizhtdp width#1\dimen@\kern2\dimen@}%
%
% Paul Taylor =  .--. .- ..- .-..   - .- -.-- .-.. --- .-.
% Code for "P" corrected 24.6.94 (Ralph Loader)
\def\the@signature{\rlap{%
  \dimen@\pixel@size\at@least\dimen@{.182\p@}\pixel@round\dimen@
   \advance\rule@height\dimen@
   \@morse0\@morse0%                                       4
   \@morse2\@morse6\@morse6\@morse2\@morse0\@morse0%    P 28
   \@morse2\@morse6\@morse0\@morse0%                    A 16
   \@morse2\@morse2\@morse6\@morse0\@morse0%            U 20
   \@morse2\@morse6\@morse2\@morse2\@morse0\@morse0%    L 24
%   \@morse0\@morse0%                           space      4
%   \@morse6\@morse0\@morse0%                           T 12
%   \@morse2\@morse6\@morse0\@morse0%                   A 16
%   \@morse6\@morse2\@morse6\@morse6\@morse0\@morse0%   Y 32
%   \@morse2\@morse6\@morse2\@morse2\@morse0\@morse0%   L 24
%   \@morse6\@morse6\@morse6\@morse0\@morse0%           O 28
%   \@morse2\@morse6\@morse2\@morse0\@morse0%%          R 20
%   \@morse0\@morse0%                           space      4
   }}%
\def\signature@countdown{10}%
\def\@signature{}%
```

I'm not sure how to trigger the production of the signature. The `\test@signature` macro is called in `\calc@horiz`.